# "A start job is running for Wait for Network to be configured" during boot on 22.04 desktop

Tags: boot, networking, netplan

This is 22.04 running on a raspberry pi 4b, desktop, not a server,vm, etc. Just a simple desktop. It has been running for over a year just fine, but after an update about a month ago, now I get the above message that delays booting. Once it's up, the network seems to run just fine. I didn't do anything to the network setup; this just happened on another similar machine that was also running fine until updated today.

```
greenman@snowball:~$ networkctl
IDX LINK  TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP      
  1 lo    loopback carrier     unmanaged

  2 eth0  ether    no-carrier  configuring

  3 wlan0 wlan     routable    unmanaged

3 links listed.


greenman@snowball:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for greenman: 
  *-interface:0             
       description: Wireless interface
       product: 43430
       vendor: Broadcom
       physical id: 1
       bus info: mmc@1:0001:1
       logical name: mmc1:0001:1
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: e4:5f:01:98:ea:71
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmfmac driverversion=7.45.241 firmware=01-703fd60 ip=192.168.2.112 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 7
       logical name: eth0
       serial: e4:5f:01:98:ea:70
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=bcmgenet driverversion=5.15.0-1037-raspi link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair

greenman@snowball:~$ sudo netplan get
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      optional: true
      dhcp4: true

greenman@snowball:/etc/netplan$ ls
50-cloud-init.yaml

(I can't get the yaml file to format correctly, sorry.)

greenman@snowball:/etc/netplan$ cat 50-cloud-init.yaml 
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
    version: 2
#    wifis:
#    wlan0:
#        access-points:
#            oblivion:
#                password: (blocked by me)
#        dhcp4: true
#        optional: true
```

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: Look at your startup logs with `sudo journalctl. -b 0`. Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager`.

Answer (score 4):

Thank You for your suggestions, and again I apologize for the formatting. After spending most of the day trying to navigate systemd's labyrinthine command structure, it appears that, while I am using Network Manager to manage my network ports, some update decided to try to install systemd-networkd to do the same thing. Two chefs in that kitchen don't work out, so:

**sudo systemctl disable systemd-networkd.service**

ended the whole nightmare.
Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Thank you sincerely. After 35387 red herrings in other replies this one actually fixed the problem.

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 1):

Please https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/2036358 for a known systemd regression in a stable release update which should now be resolved.